# Getting colour values from various positions in a bitmap c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, bitmap

I have a bitmap and I am wanting to get the colour values from the pixels but only in certain areas of the image. I am wanting to the get the pixels of a image for the full width and only a bit of the height (say height =1) and then I want to move the position to one down and get the same values.

I am using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 302; i++)
{ 
    Rectangle cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, i, 514, 1);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format = bm.PixelFormat;
    Bitmap cloneBitmap = bm.Clone(cloneRect, format);
    bitMapList.Add(cloneBitmap);
}

foreach (Bitmap bmp in bitMapList)
{
    c = bmp.GetPixel(514, 1);
    r = Convert.ToInt16(c.R);
    lumi.Add(r);
}
```

The for statement to create the areas I want on the bitmap and then the foreach to loop through these bitmaps and then get the values. Only problem is I am getting the error message "Parameter must be positive and < Width."

On the line

```
c = bmp.GetPixel(514, 1);
```

anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the pixel you are getting is inside of the image (which must not be the case). You could wrap this in a call to run a check first something like:

```
public static Color GetPixelSafe(Bitmap image, int x, int y) {
    if (x >= image.Width) x = image.Width - 1;
    else if (x < 0) x = 0;
    if (y >= image.Height) y = image.Height - 1;
    else if (y < 0) y = 0;

    return image.GetPixel(x, y);
}
```

Now, this is not going to fix your processing algorithm itself, but it should at least fix the exception. One other pointer is that if you are going to be processing *lots* of color values and performance is a concern you should really consider using `image.LockBits` instead of `GetPixel`. For more information on that see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: this worked thank you! I'm just creating a basic version to see if it will work, will take a look into the image.LockBits so thanks for that too!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 514 is bigger then your image actual Width. How did you come up with that number?

Comment: my image width is 514

Comment: and pixels are 0 based so that means 513 should be the number. Anyway why are you hardcoding that? Are you always going to work with 514 width images?

Comment: no it wont be hard coded in the future but at the moment i'm doing it very basic just to check I can do it